# Explicit constructor taking multiple arguments

Tags: c++, explicit-constructor

Does making a constructor having multiple arguments `explicit` have any (useful) effect?

Example:

```
class A {
    public:
        explicit A( int b, int c ); // does explicit have any (useful) effect?
};
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Up until C++11, yeah, no reason to use `explicit` on a multi-arg constructor.

That changes in C++11, because of initializer lists. Basically, copy-initialization (but not direct initialization) with an initializer list requires that the constructor not be marked `explicit`.

Example:

```
struct Foo { Foo(int, int); };
struct Bar { explicit Bar(int, int); };

Foo f1(1, 1); // ok
Foo f2 {1, 1}; // ok
Foo f3 = {1, 1}; // ok

Bar b1(1, 1); // ok
Bar b2 {1, 1}; // ok
Bar b3 = {1, 1}; // NOT OKAY
```

Comment: I think this answer would be better with "Why would I want that" or "When is this usefull" explanation.

Comment: @MateuszL Edgar's answer gives probably the best argument for why it might be useful (and arguably deserves the tick). The reason it's *there*, though, is simply because it's the logical extension of the existing semantics for `explicit`. I would not personally bother making multi-arg constructors `explicit`.

Answer (score 38):

You'd stumble upon it for brace initialization (for instance in arrays)

```
struct A {
        explicit A( int b, int c ) {}
};

struct B {
         B( int b, int c ) {}
};

int main() {
    B b[] = {{1,2}, {3,5}}; // OK

    A a1[] = {A{1,2}, A{3,4}}; // OK

    A a2[] = {{1,2}, {3,4}}; // Error

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

The excellent answers by @StoryTeller and @Sneftel are the main reason. However, IMHO, this makes sense (at least I do it), as part of future proofing later changes to the code. Consider your example:

```
class A {
    public:
        explicit A( int b, int c ); 
};
```

This code doesn't directly benefit from `explicit`.

Some time later, you decide to add a default value for `c`, so it becomes this:

```
class A {
    public:
        A( int b, int c=0 ); 
};
```

When doing this, you're focussing on the `c` parameter - in retrospect, it should have a default value. You're not necessarily focussing on whether `A` itself should be implicitly constructed. Unfortunately, this change makes `explicit` relevant again.

So, in order to convey that a ctor is `explicit`, it might pay to do so when first writing the method.

Comment: But what about the case when the maintainer adds that default and concludes that the result **should** be available as a converting constructor? Now they have to **remove** that `explicit` that's been there forever, and tech support will be inundated with calls about that change and spend **hours** explaining that `explicit` was just noise, and that removing it is harmless. Personally, I'm not very good at predicting the future; it's hard enough deciding what an interface should look like **now**.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's a good point. I personally think that the two cases are asymmetric, and that it's much more common when making parameters default (or removing them) to inadvertently make the class implicitly constructible, then to actually realize at the same time that in retrospect it should have be so. That being said, these are "soft" considerations, and might vary between people/projects/etc., or even just be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my five cents to this discussion:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int, double) {}
};

struct Bar {
    explicit Bar(int, double) {}
};

void foo(const Foo&) {}
void bar(const Bar&) {}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    foo({ 42, 42.42 }); // valid
    bar({ 42, 42.42 }); // invalid
    return 0;
}
```

As you can easily see, `explicit` prevents from using initializer list alongside with `bar` function bacause the constructor of `struct Bar` is declared as `explicit`.

Comment: I typically declare multi-parameter constructors explicit, for this reason - forces the use of the class name at the function call location.