# Overloading explicit constructor in C++

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, overloading, explicit

I am reading a book and got some code for class designing that I do not really understand.

```
class Queue {
public:
    Queue(size_t capacity) {}
    explicit Queue(int capacity) : entries_(capacity) {}
...
private:
    vector<int> entries_;
...
};
```

And another similar one,

```
class LruCache {
public:
    LruCache(size_t capacity) {}
    explicit LruCache(int capacity) : capacity_(capacity) {}
...
private:
    int capacity_;
...
};
```

I have two questions,

1. Could we overload methods purely on the `explicit` keyword, like the `const` keyword? In my case, the argument type is a little different though, an `int` and a `size_t`.
2. A more important question is why. Why do we need a overloaded `explicit` constructor? In C++ primer, I believe it says overloading functions with similar argument types is not recommended.

edit:

My 2nd question is more about the code piece above. Why does it have a constructor with an `int` argument and then an `explicit` constructor with a `size_t` argument, and `int` and `size_t` are types that are really close. So it should not be necessary to define two constructors, for each of them. I believe the author defines two constructors for a reason, but I do not know why, and that should be my 2nd question about. Not a general question about what does `explicit` keyword do. Sorry.

Comment: `int` and `size_t` are different types. The code isn't "overloaded on explicit", it's overloaded on `size_t` and `int`;  and if an explicit constructor is chosen where it is not allowed, the code is ill-formed

Comment: The `explicit` is not part of the function signature, so functions can't be overloaded by it.

Comment: Does the book talk about why it has these constructors? It seems like a poor idea to me just based on what is posted.

Comment: 1. No; 2. explicit has nothing to do with overloading, it simply prevents given ctor to be considered for automatic conversions; affects only one-parameter ctors

Comment: @C.M. - It affects more since C++11. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122101/explicit-constructor-taking-multiple-arguments

Comment: Folks, your answers would be excellent if you wrote them as answers instead of comments...

Comment: @M.M I guess not. That's why I am asking. I ignored it when I first saw it because I thought it was not a big deal but it keeps coming again. The book is "Elements of Progamming Interviews" btw

Comment: @NickyC I cannot answer part 2 of the question, it would require more context (and it might turn out that the answer is just "there is no answer, this code is rubbish")

Answer (score 3):

> Could we overload methods purely on the `explicit` keyword

No.

> Why do we need a overloaded explicit constructor?

To avoid implicit conversions.

Let's say `Queue` had been defined as:

```
class Queue {
  public:
    // No constructor with a size_t.
    Queue(int capacity) {}
  ...
};
```

With that, an `int` will be implicitly converted to `Queue` when needed.

```
void bar(Queue const& q) { ... }

bar(10); // This would be valid without the explicit keyword.
         // 10 will be implicitly converted to Queue(10).
```

Sometimes such implicit conversions lead to hard to understand and maintain code. The `explicit` qualifier is used to avoid such implicit conversions.

With the `explicit` qualifier in place, you'll be required to use

```
bar(Queue(10));
```

which is a lot easier to understand.

> Why does it have a constructor with an `size_t` argument and then an `explicit` constructor with a `int` argument,

I don't see any reason why you would need the two overloads -- `explicit` or not. If the book does not explain why they are needed, we can only attribute it to lack of clarity on the part of the author.

Comment: `bar(10)` is valid in the existing code though, since the non-explicit `size_t` constructor is chosen. (Which has different semantics ot the existing constructor)

Comment: That shouldn't be true.  "10" shouldn't have type size_t.  bar(10z) or bar((size_t)10) could choose the Queue(size_t) constructor.